# Support for loose collection validation in a Java unit testing framework

Tags: java, unit-testing

Any Java unit testing framework that supports writing unit testing code like this:

```
Collection<AType> myCollection = objectUnderTest.doSomething();
assertCollectionContainsAtleast(myCollection, "a Expected value");
```

Meaning what I would like is some sort of iteration support with some sort of matcher attached.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [Hamcrest](http://code.google.com/p/hamcrest/wiki/Tutorial), which contains assertions for many things, including collections. You can use `hasItem`, `hasKey`, `hasValue` etc.

Comment: Alright thanks! For anybody reading this, here is what it would like using Hamcrest
Matcher<AType> myMatcher= hasProperty("aPropertyInAType",is("aPropertyValue"));
assertThat(myCollection,hasItem(myMatcher));

Comment: Mix Hamcrest with JDave(.org) and you will most likely never look back - welcome to the world of BDD.

Answer (score 0):

You might also take a look at [Unitil's](http://www.unitils.org/tutorial.html) assertion utilities.